# Rename files with random names in a folder

Tags: batch-file

I need some code that will rename multiple (bulk or all) files in a folder.

I found a [batch file script](http://www.howtogeek.com/57661/stupid-geek-tricks-randomly-rename-every-file-in-a-directory/); however, it renames with numbers only; which is not exactly what I'm looking for.  Nevertheless, I download it tested it.

I don't fully understand how to modify this .bat file code to rename with strings (rather than with just numbers).

Example:

In a folder there are 100 images and all numbered with some digits or names.  Assume that all images are belongs to "john" , so i want to rename all images with "john+ a random string".

The 'random string' comes from an array of 3000 English words, (downloaded from a dictionary).

In the script the 3000 names are fixed, except the 1st, which is settable (john, mary, sai, pavan etc...)

The end result is to rename all image files; ie: john good, john bad, john eating, john idiol, john silly etc.........

How might this be done?

Comment: hi Prasanth, couldn't you use something more powerful than DOS? it's not impossible but with some more advanced scripting language it would be easier...

Comment: Is your list of words in a single flat text file, one word per line?  Is speed a factor?

Comment: The image files have a specific extension?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set baseName=john

rem Load the list of 3000 words
set num=0
for /F %%a in (dictionary.txt) do (
   set /A num+=1
   set word[!num!]=%%a
)

rem Rename the files
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /A-D *.*') do (
   set /A randomIndex=!random! * num / 32768 + 1
   for /F %%r in ("!randomIndex!") do ren "%%a" "%baseName% !word[%%r]!%%~Xa"
)
```

Comment: This will rename the batch file too, and dictionary.txt

Comment: Yes. Both files may be in a different directory, but I think it is easier that the "image files" have a specific extension. I will wait for further details from the OP before made modifications...